# Qt QProcess failed to start on a command that works on the cmd prompt

Tags: windows, qt

When running this command from the command line prompt:

```
magick convert report_pages/test_0.png report_pages/test_1.png report_pages/test_2.png report_pages/test.pdf
```

It works perfectly. Generating a PDF from the three test png images. The location where I'm running this command is the location of the Qt Application compiled executable that I'm developing. This is a Windows application.

I want to run that same command from said Qt application.

In order to do this I use this code:

```
    QProcess pdfmerge;

#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
    arguments.prepend("convert");
#endif

    pdfmerge.start(PDF_GEN_APPLICATION,arguments);        
    bool all_good = pdfmerge.waitForFinished();

    this->cmd = QString(PDF_GEN_APPLICATION) + " " + arguments.join(" ");
```

Inside a class. PDF_GEN_APPLICATION is just a define for the string "magick".
Arguments is a list first of the word "convert" and then of the list of PNG.
As a matter a fact I took the string that I run in the CMD console from the output of  printing this->cmd.

When I try to run the Qt Application I get the error that the process "Failed To Start". With no other clues, I was wondering if anyone here could help me. In order to run my Qt Application I just press play in QtCreator, in case that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Did you check the privileges, e.g., if you have to run it as an administrator etc.? You could double-check the process runtime path before starting or check the exit code (`pdfmerge.exitCode()`). How is `arguments` defined? Is there possibly a string conversion or encoding problem?

Comment: Exit code is 0, because the process failed to start. Arguments is the list of arguments: first convert and the the list of the png files. Also I don't run anything in admin mode. So if the command line tool works with no admin, how can that be the problem here?

Comment: If you want people to help you, please edit your question and provide the *full* code needed for reproduction, which will include the definition of `arguments` and `PDF_GEN_APPLICATION`. Moreover, why are you providing `this->cmd = ...`?

Comment: Beucase the print out of this->cmd is literally what I run in the command line and it works. And the argument list is the string list of images. There is nothing more. Also I explained that PDF_GEN_APPLICATION is a define for "magick",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command should be "magick" and the first argument should be "convert".

e.g.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QProcess p;
    p.start("magick", {"convert", "test.bmp", "test.png"});
    p.waitForFinished();
    return p.exitCode();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. However I switched it and I still get the same problem

Comment: I have added an example, which I've tested. Are you sure that the magick program is on your path?

Comment: You are right. Here is the thing, I used windeployqt so I could run the application from the shell without having to launch it from QtCreator. And when I did, with your change, it worked (It didn't before). So now the problem is something else. Thank you!!